# Unsure why link is grey

Tags: html, css

```css
.navigation{
 float: right;
 margin-top:23px;
 font-weight:bolder;
}

.navigation ul{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
}

.navigation ul li{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left:40px;

}

.navigation ul li a{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#a7a7a7;
 display: block;
 padding-left:7px;
 padding-right:7px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#fff;
 display: block;
 background:#d23131;
 padding-left:7px;
 padding-right:7px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
}

.navigationactive{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#fff;
 display: block;
 background:#d23131;
 padding-left:7px;
 padding-right:7px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FREEBIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigationactive">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want the link with the navigationactive class to be white, but it is getting it's class from the div that it is in, and I am unsure how to fix it.

To clarify, the text in the red box should be white even before it is hovered over.

Comment: use your browser's debugger. it'll show you what rules are being applied, which were overiden, etc...

Comment: check .navigation ul li a rule

Comment: For reference: [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 2):

Just make the rule for the `.navigationactive` class more specific e.g. `.navigation ul li a.navigationactive`

As it was previously, `.navigationactive` was not being recognized because of the more specific rule, `.navigation ul li a`.

On a side note, you can greatly reduce the amount of CSS needed to get the same result. For example, the `a:hover` should inherit all of the rules of the corresponding `a` so, in this case, you don't need to repeat all of the rules if you're just changing the background color on hover.

```css
.navigation{
 float: right;
 margin-top:23px;
}

.navigation ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.navigation ul li{
 float: right;
 margin-left:40px;
}

.navigation ul li a {
 font-weight:bolder;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#a7a7a7;
 display: block;
    padding: 2px 7px;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover,
.navigation ul li a.navigationactive {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background:#d23131;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FREEBIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigationactive">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to how css precedence works, the first presedence is id (#) and the lower is class (.) a bigger cascade rule has a bigger precedense that a shorter cascade rule so:
`.class ul li a` has a bigger precedence that `.class` to fix the issue just add a bigger cascade rule as `.navigation ul li a.navigationactive`

```css
.navigation{
 float: right;
 margin-top:23px;
 font-weight:bolder;
}

.navigation ul{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
}

.navigation ul li{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left:40px;

}

.navigation ul li a{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#a7a7a7;
 display: block;
 padding-left:7px;
 padding-right:7px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#fff;
 display: block;
 background:#d23131;
 padding-left:7px;
 padding-right:7px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
}

.navigation ul li a.navigationactive{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#fff;
 display: block;
 background:#d23131;
 padding-left:7px;
 padding-right:7px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FREEBIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigationactive">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```